# ibus can't add French in setting

Tags: linux, keyboard, multilingual, input-method

I'm running RedHat 6.9 now and need to type French. However I can't add French cause it doesn't show in the select box. I've installed ibus-m17n and it support French.

I have install ibus-m17n package and the French pack for the system, but still can't find French in the select box.
[ibus-m17n package has been installed](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QiMKY.png)
[There still no French, just CJK and some other languages](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4O7Qt.png)

Comment: Sounds more like a question for unix.stackexchange.com. See https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/ibus

Comment: thanks a lot! I'll check if there are some similar questions.